# Eclipse PDE: Launching the current project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I am writing a plugin for Eclipse.  This plugin allows the user to create a new project, edit it, and then launch the project to an external tool.  The project is NOT a Java project.  It is my own custom project which basically consists of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I am having trouble actually launching my project.

I have a launch delegate (ILaunchConfigurationDelegate) with the following code:

```
public class LaunchConfigurationDelegate1  implements
    ILaunchConfigurationDelegate {

    public LaunchConfigurationDelegate1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode,
            ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

    System.out.println("You clicked run!!!");
}
}
```

This is simple and works fine.  The problem is that I have no idea how to get a handle to the selected project.  The following assigns "null" to project:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject();
```

When I made my delegate a AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate, this also return null:

```
this.getJavaProject(configuration).getProject().getName()
```

I must be missing something obvious.  What I need to do is A) get a hold of the current project, B) copy it to a new directory, and C) then launch an external tool.  I've done B & C with hardcoded values, but I cannot figure out how to dynamically get the project for part A.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't launch a project directly in eclipse. You launch a launch configuration, and you get this as parameter to launch method. You need to make sure that your launch configuration (you will probably need a custom one) contains enough data to allow you to launch (probably you can have a link to a project in launch configuration).

You will probably get better answers to this kind of questions on one of [eclipse mailing lists](http://www.eclipse.org/mail/). It's also a good idea to get a source for some similar kind of project (JDT,CDT?) and see how it's done there.